# In Tomcat 7, can I use regular expressions in <url-pattern>?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting

Does Tomcat 7 have such a facility?  Although I could write a filter to parse regular expression in url, it would make another project.  I think such a facility should be provided in mainstream servlet containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Servlet API specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) does not specify that. So no one container supports it.

Best what you can get is using [Tuckey's URLRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/). It's much similar to HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`.